# How to send value of button to textBox?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button with value = "7" (string) or value = 7 (double).

Also i want a textbox, that when i click said button the number 7 or the string "7" should also get written in that textbox.

My button:

```
<input type="button" name="btnSeven" id="btnSeven" value="7" onclick="setText7()"  />
```

My textBox:

```
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('btnSeven').addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value + document.getElementById('btnSeven').value;
    });
}
```

when getting a `.value` from a button object, it will always return a string, event if it's an int or double.

hope that helped.

Comment: Ok, but what if we have more that two buttons and we want that textBox remember last number. For example we click 7 button and it will type 7, then we clik 5 button and we will have 75 in textBox, how to do that?

Comment: Thank You very much. Now I have another problem, maybe you know how to get expression when I click the btnOne -> btn0 -> btnPlus -> btn2 -> btn1 -> btnEqual I want to have this expression: 10+21= and after clicki in btnEqual I want to get sum of this expresson and get only one value in textBox 31 like in simple windows calculator. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
<script>
    function setText7(obj){
    var val = obj.value;
    console.log(val);
    document.getElementById('textBox').value = val;
}
</script>
<input type="button" name="btnSeven" id="btnSeven" value="7" onclick="setText7(this)">
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" value=""/>
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sh3Mz/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" name="btnSeven" id="btnSeven" value="7" onclick="getthevalue()" />
    <input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" value="" />
    <h3 id="res"></h3>
</div>
```

```
function getthevalue() {
    document.getElementById('btnSeven').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value +
            document.getElementById('btnSeven').value;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

function getthevalue() {
    document.getElementById('btnSeven').addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById('textBox').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value+
        document.getElementById('btnSeven').value;
    })};

Comment: Posting a unformatted code as answer will only get you votes down.